# How can I fetch from xml file the wanted information to listbox using combobox?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I am trying to create this program which fetches hockey players names by the team from xml file. The selection should be done by choosing the team from combobox. joukkuenimi is team in the xml file. So far I can get the players from the xml file, but I don't know how to specify the team in code.

```
  public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            cmbJoukkueet.Items.Add("saipa");
            cmbJoukkueet.Items.Add("sport");

        }
        XmlReader lukija = XmlReader.Create("SMLiiga.xml");
        private void cmbJoukkueet_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            lstPelaajat.Items.Clear();





            if (cmbJoukkueet.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {


                joukkueenPelaajatListaLaatikkoon();


            }
             else if (cmbJoukkueet.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {


                joukkueenPelaajatListaLaatikkoonn();


            }

            lukija.Close();
            lukija = XmlReader.Create("SMLiiga.xml");
        }

        void joukkueenPelaajatListaLaatikkoon()
        {

            while (lukija.Read())
            {
                if ((lukija.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && lukija.Name == "Joukkue"))
                {
                   break; 
                }

                if (lukija.Name == "sukunimi" && lukija.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    lukija.Read();
                    lstPelaajat.Items.Add(lukija.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        void joukkueenPelaajatListaLaatikkoonn()
        {

            while (lukija.Read())
            {
                if ((lukija.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement && lukija.Name == "Joukkue"))
                {
                    break; 
                }

                if (lukija.Name == "sukunimi" && lukija.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    lukija.Read();
                    lstPelaajat.Items.Add(lukija.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
 <Joukkue>
     <joukkuenimi>Saipa</joukkuenimi>
     <Pelaajat>
     <Pelaaja>
        <sukunimi>Torikka</sukunimi>
        <pelNro>2</pelNro>
     </Pelaaja>
```

I thought the by adding "" to cmbJoukkueet.Items it would work, but no.

Comment: You can try Nesting the problem. So  you first select a team then nest their team players by encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I managed to solve the task by myself. Took me some hours, but did it, and now I am ashamed by this mess of code.

Comment: Could you tell us what you did? Might save somebody else from several hours of scratching their heads.